# Text Gutter in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup: https://jsbin.com/xovupozopo/edit?html,css,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="text">V</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Less:

```
@fontsize: 128pt;
@size: 95pt;

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10pt 10pt 0 10pt;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt;
  border-radius: 4pt;
  box-shadow: 0 3pt 5pt rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.text {
  font-size: @fontsize;
  text-align: center middle;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);

}

body {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: enter code here]

Obviously it's too tall. I can't seem to reduce the size by fiddling with margin or padding on either the span or the div.

How can I reduce the vertical height here proportionally so I can get it to a fixed width scaling square?

Comment: You mean you want the font size to scale with the containing square?

Comment: use `transform: scale(1,0.8);` on the `.box`

Comment: Try changing the font 'Josefin Sans' for another font, example 'Arial'.

Comment: You may take a look at transform (and display to trigger transform on span) : https://jsbin.com/kitifoqaju/1/edit?html,css,output  (about one tenth down of the font-size  https://jsbin.com/sanacarigi/1/edit?html,css,output )

Comment: Please close the `.box` div for the Validity sake!

Answer (score 1):

Display `.text` as `block`, set its `height` and `overflow`:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10pt;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt;
  border-radius: 4pt;
  box-shadow: 0 3pt 5pt rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 95pt;
  text-align: center;
  height: .8em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

body {
  background-color: #693;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="box">
  <span class="text">V</span>
</div>
```

Comment: fontsize was set to 128pt ;)